# Store Json data in android?

Tags: android, json

I am developing an application in which i am getting data through Json which includes text, images both. When user runs my application for the first time, data should be stored somewhere so that next time he/she can run the app without using internet. Can anybody suggest me any solution?

Comment: Show what are you trying to do

Comment: Please clarify how your JSON is supposed to represent images.

Comment: Did you read [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)?

Comment: Store the json results in local database (sqlite database)...next time retrieve the data from sqlite when there is no internet connection...

Comment: @Vamshi you are right but Sqlite is very slow when we talk about real time application so i tried with DB4o but not very successful.

Comment: @ClassStacker it is getting the url of the image from Json and i am using UrlImageViewHelper for loading the image.

Comment: @Rohit Okay then you'll probably discard the URL and store the image outside of JSON as a file.

Comment: my data is not static bro.... so i have to get it through the Json...

Comment: @PankajKumar I did not say using preferences is a bad option. I was trying to implement what you said but after sometime, ohh you delete your answer and down vote my question and still i am not ok with the Shared Preference because expert says don't use shared preferences with heavy data it becomes lazy in that case. There are more better options like Db4o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared Preferences is the best option for you as it is permanent light-weight storage in android.An good example of shared preferences in android is to storing Highest score of game in your device.[See here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: I'm not so sure. The OP says he wants to store images. Before he clarifies how those will be represented and what size they are, it's a bit dangerous to point him towards a storage mechanism which is based on XML, with all the resource overhead.

Comment: if the data is going to be static and small through the application life then shared preferences are good to go.

Comment: Share Preferences is best solution in that case when our data is very small like score but in my case there are images and details of things.

Comment: approximately what will be the size of your data?

Comment: images could be 300-500kb
data could be 10-20kb

Comment: but how will it deal with images??

Comment: see, store your complete Json string in shared Preferences and then parse the images from this json whenever you want you can also update json response when you whenever you have internet connection.